# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

Tags: python, database, flask

First of all, I know there are other posts on here with this title.However, they have not been helpful. What I am trying to do is create a database using db.create_all() in sqlalchemy. However, I keep getting either the error on title or an instance directory that has my database file. I am new to this whole programming thing.

The two methods I have tried are written in the code section. The error I get with one of the methods is, sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8). The other method creates the database, but saves the file in an instance directory that is not part of my package, and cannot run.

Here are the articles I looked up for this problem:

https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sqlalchemy/ https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+reply+to+a+user+in+stack+overflow (This is another Youtube tutorial I watched. If you want to watch it, the timestamp is 1:37:34) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-to-interact-with-databases-in-a-flask-application https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/ https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/

Here is my code:

main.py

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

init.py

```
from flask import Flask  
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy  
import os  
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "hjshjhdjah kjshkjdhjs"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'database.db' #first method  
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(app.instance_path,"database.db") # second method
    db.init_app(app)

# from where the views blueprint is located import what is the name.
from  .views import views
from .auth import auth

app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")

from .models import User, Note
create_database(app)
return app


def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + "database.db"):
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
    print('Created Database!')
```

models.py

```
from . import db 
from flask_login import UserMixin 
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship("Note")
```

Any help in solving this problem is appreciated. Just so you know, I am new to this whole programming thing. If it seems like an easy fix, that is why I am having a problem with this.